# Copy data from one page to SQLite database on another page Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

Hi I have a Portable Xamarin app from which I want to copy data from one page and move it to another page which contains a SQLite database, however I have no idea how to get about doing that. I have created a button using XAML:

```
<Button Text = "Copy Password"
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   VerticalOptions="Center"
   Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
```

And this is how I am currently handling the Button_Clicked

```
async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage
        {
            BindingContext = new User()

        });
```

It navigates to a page which allows data to be input. I want it to be so that the data that I want copied from the first page, already populates a certain input field. e.g the Name field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried searching but I haven't found anything useful yet.

**EDIT** 
I solved it thanks to Cole Xia's help. I just needed to add `BindingContext = new User { Name = "Cole"}`to the Button_Clicked code. Instead of hardcoding the name, I used a variable from another method so it'll copy the value of the variable over to the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In First Page :

```
//navigate to another page and pass the data.
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage()
     {
         BindingContext = new User { Name = "Cole"}
     });
}
```

Second Page

XMAL:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Code behind:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await insertDB();
}

Task insertDB()
{
    User user = this.BindingContext as User;
    //insert user with db operation
}
```

Model:

```
public class User {
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So what would I put in the getUserfromDB? I have another method where I am querying the data from the db                                          
`public Task<List<User>> GetApplicationsNotDoneAsync()

       {

            return database.QueryAsync<User>("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE [Done] = 0");

        }`

Comment: @stackman your method returns a list ,you want to display them with a listview？

Comment: In that case i did. Now I want to insert data from another page into the database, so do i use SQL code as such: INSERT INTO User [(Name)] VALUES("Bob")  ?

Comment: @stackman alright, you want to populate the data (copy from the first page ) to the listView  and insert it into DB on second page?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i want to do, sorry if i wasn't being clear